# AJAX JQuery delete from html but not from mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

What is wrong here?

My PHP/HTML (The only part that matters):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace("-","/",$_POST['dateOfEntry'])));
    $username = $_POST['user'];

    $query = 'SELECT `ID`, `Date`, `Description`, `TypeOfDowntime`, `Machine#` FROM `machineissuesreport` WHERE `Date`="'.$date.'" AND `UpdatedBy` = "'.$username.'" ORDER BY `ID` DESC';

    $conn = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($conn))
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td style="text-align: center" width="5px"><input type="button" name="edit" value="Edit"></td>';
        echo '<td style="text-align: center" width="5px"><a href="#" id="'.$row['ID'].'" class="delete">Delete</a></td>';
        echo '<td style="display: none;"><input type="hidden" value='.$row['ID'].'></td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['Date'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['Description'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['TypeOfDowntime'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['Machine#'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }

}
?>
```

My Ajax/Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('.delete').click(function()
    {
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?"))
        {
            var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
            var $ele = $(this).parent().parent();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'machineEntryLogEdit.php',
                data: {'del_id':'del_id'},
                success: function(data)
                {
                    $ele.fadeOut().remove();            
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error)
                {
                    alert(this);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

My PHP (on an external script: machineEntryLogEdit.php):

```
include('connServer.php');

$deleteID = $_POST['del_id'];

$query = 'DELETE FROM `machineissuesreport` WHERE `ID` ="'.$deleteID.'"';

$result = mysqli_connect($connection, $query);

if(isset($result)) 
{
   echo "YES";
} 
else 
{
   echo "NO";
}

?>
```

I have searched around and around for solutions but no avail. The only things it does is delete the record from the HTML table, but not from the database, causing the supposed-to-be-deleted row to reappear after refresh. I am still very new to AJAX (in fact I just learned it myself today) and still reading the documentations and forums. Thanks.

Comment: `{'del_id':'del_id'}`, did you mean `{'del_id':del_id}`? As is you are just sending the actual string `"del_id"` instead of whatever your variable `del_id` contains

Comment: Do you receive any error in your console log? Did you include your jQuery?

Comment: @LoganWayne no error sir. And yes I imported jQuery from the URL. `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be `data: {'del_id': del_id}` remove quotes so it react as a variable, not just a single string. And one more thing, **your delete query does not execute** cause you're using :

```
$result = mysqli_connect($connection, $query);
```

Should be `mysqli_query` like the one you did on selecting data's part:

```
$query = 'DELETE FROM `machineissuesreport` WHERE `ID` ="'.$deleteID.'"';
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

Comment: yes sir, I have tried `data: {'del_id': del_id},` ,`data: {'del_id': 'del_id'},`, `data: {del_id: 'del_id'},`, `data: {del_id: del_id},` but none of them seem to work..

Comment: Thank you sir. That solved the problem. I should have slept earlier last night.

Comment: Glad to hear that and you're welcome mate. Go sleep now(bedtime story).

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you didn't pass the `submit` variable in your data.  If you want to include a form you need to pass the data, right now the server is receiving only one parameter, `del_id`